# How to set up a shared /vagrant directory on an OSX Vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I'm using [jhcook/osx-elcapitan-10.11](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/jhcook/boxes/osx-elcapitan-10.11) as a base box. I'd like to have a shared `/vagrant` directory but it's "not working", because the guest additions do not install in OSX and therefore the `/vagrant` directory does not mount. I've been told there is a [workaround](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html) and that is to use NFS. However, it needs to be configured on the host machine and you can put an entry in your Vagrantfile.

According to the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html):

> If you are using the VirtualBox provider, you will also need to make sure you have a [private network set up](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html). This is due to a limitation of VirtualBox's built-in networking. With VMware, you do not need this.

I am using VirtualBox.

Again referencing the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html):

> The easiest way to use a private network is to allow the IP to be assigned via DHCP.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
end
```

And then back to setting up "nfs"

> To enable NFS, just add the type: "nfs" flag onto your synced folder:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ...

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
end
```

But it isn't working. Below is my `Vagrantfile`. Also note I also got an error about USB not working, the workaround is to disable usb, following [this tutorial](https://hameedullah.com/vagrant-101-basic-virtual-machine-customizations.html).

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
.
.
.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "jhcook/osx-elcapitan-10.11"

  # private network setup
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  # enable NFS
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"

  # disable usb
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # VM Customizations go here
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usb", "off"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usbehci", "off"]
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to an [issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1437) the solution is to use a static ip. According to the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html):

> You can also specify a static IP address for the machine. This lets you access the Vagrant managed machine using a static, known IP. The Vagrantfile for a static IP looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
end
```

So now my working `Vagrantfile` looks like:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
.
.
.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "jhcook/osx-elcapitan-10.11"

  # private network setup
  # config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.10.2"

  # enable NFS
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"

  # disable usb
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # VM Customizations go here
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usb", "off"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usbehci", "off"]
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

woot woot :)

```
osx-el-capitan ❯ ls
Vagrantfile
osx-el-capitan ❯ echo "Hello world?" > hello-world
osx-el-capitan ❯ vagrant ssh
Last login: Tue Sep  6 09:49:21 2016 from 10.0.2.2
This-MacBook-Pro:~ vagrant$ cat /vagrant/hello-world
Hello world?
This-MacBook-Pro:~ vagrant$ echo ":)"
:)
This-MacBook-Pro:~ vagrant$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
        options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=2b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,TSO4>
        ether 08:00:27:d2:a9:5f
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fed2:a95f%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
        inet 10.0.2.15 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.2.255
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
        media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=2b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,TSO4>
        ether 08:00:27:76:d5:29
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe76:d529%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5
        inet 192.168.10.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.10.255
        nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
        media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
```